# flutter: No named parameter with the name 'overflow', overflow: Overflow.visible,

Tags: flutter, dart, stack

i updated my flutter today and now the overflow parameter in stack widget no longer works.

```
Flutter 1.22.0-10.0.pre.252 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 78929661fb (5 hours ago) • 2020-09-18 08:08:30 -0700
Engine • revision 2abe69c608
Tools • Dart 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-136.0.dev)
```

im using badges and stack widgets everywhere, what do i do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you replace all the `overflow: Overflow.visible,` with `clipBehavior: Clip.none,` or a similar Clip behaviour in all the Stack widgets that had the overflow property

Answer (score -3):

I switched flutter channel from master to stable and now its working fine :/

Comment: By switching the channel it can't be working fine for anyone. we need to replace all the ```overflow: Overflow.visible,``` with```clipBehavior: Clip.none,```